# Any explanation for the contradiction explained below?

Tags: c++, c++11, nested-class

B.Stroustrup gives the following example in **Section 16.2.13 Member Types** of his new book "TCPL" 4th edition:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Tree{
    using value_type = T;                   // member alias
    enum Policy { rb, splay, treeps };      // member enum
    class Node{                             // member class
        Node* right;
        Node* left;
        value_type value;
    public:
        void f(Tree*);
    };
    Node* top;
public:
    void g(Node*);
};

template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::Node::f(Tree* p)
{
  //top = right;                            // error: no object of type tree specified
    p->top = right;                         // OK
    value_type v = left->value;             // OK: value_type is not associated with an object
}

template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::g(Tree::Node* p)
{
  //value_type val = right->value;          // error: no object of type Tree::Node
    value_type v = p->right->value;         // error: Node::right is private
    p->f(this);                             // OK
}    

int main()
{
}
```

The expression `value_type v = p->right->value;` according to Stroustrup is in error, but the code compiles in clang and g++.

Comment: You need to instantiate the template to get an error. [Here's your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52b4fb6a824f5b6f) with a few alterations.

Comment: @chris you should just make it an answer.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, Good point. I'll never find a dupe.

Comment: And, note that you could a particular instantiation well-formed by explicitly specializing `Tree::Node`.

Comment: @chris I'm not familiar with templates. But why do the order errors show without the instantiation?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil, They're different classes of errors. Putting `difjsiofjsof;` in there will clearly give an error, but note, as Potatoswatter says, that the other error can possibly exist or not based on what `T` is. I'm not 100% on which errors are and aren't dependent on instantiation, as that very example could work if one specialization had that random text as a data member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your template needs to be instantiated before the error will appear. One way to do this is to make an object and call `g` on it ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d26288c826582dad)):

```
Tree<int>().g(nullptr);
```